# Task concerning Stone Weierstrass

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the open unit circle with center $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $\overline D$ be the closed unit circle with center $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $\mathbb{C}[z]_{\big|\overline D}$ be the set of all functions $f:\overline D\to\mathbb{C}$ of polynomials of the type $f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{N}a_jz^j$.

The task has something to do with the complex version of Stone-Weierstrass.

> I need to show which of the conditions for the sentence are not fulfilled:

$\mathbb{C}[z]_{\big|\overline D}$ is a algebra in $C_b(D,\mathbb{C})$ where $C_b(D,\mathbb{C})$ describes the set of all continuous and bounded functions from $D$ to $\mathbb{C}$. I think there should be no problem because $\mathbb{C}[z]_{\big|\overline D}$ is a linear subspace and for $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[z]_{\big|\overline D}$ $\Rightarrow fg \in \mathbb{C}[z]_{\big|\overline D}$.

Then the next one: $z_1 \neq z_2 \Rightarrow f(z_1) \neq f(z_2)$ should be no problem either by choosing $f(z)=z$ And for every $z$ there exists a $f$ such that $f(z)\neq 0$ by simply choosing $f=1$ constant.

So If I didn't make any mistakes so far the only thing that can go wrong is $f \in \mathbb{C}[z]_{\big|\overline D} \Rightarrow \overline f \in \mathbb{C}[z]_{\big|\overline D}$.

$\overline f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{N}\overline a_j z^{-j}$. Is this not in $\mathbb{C}[z]_{\big|\overline D}$ because $z$ can have negative exponents?

Comment: It is true that $\sum_{j=0}^N \overline a_j z^{-j}$ is not in $\left.\Bbb C[z]\right\rvert_{\overline D}$, but it's not true that $\overline f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^N \overline a_j z^{-j}$ (unless $N=0$). In fact, $$\overline f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^N \overline a_j \overline z^{j}.$$

Comment: So for $f \in \mathbb{C}[z]_{\big|\overline D} \Rightarrow \overline f \in \mathbb{C}[z]_{\big|\overline D}$ is fulfilled?

Comment: I'm wondering, is $\overline f$ a polynomial of the type $f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{N}a_jz^j$?

Comment: No, it isn't${}$.